# Is this a good approach to replace mysqli_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this a good approach to replace `mysqli_num_rows`?

`$db` is a `PDO` instance. ..

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$result_set = $result->fetchAll();
$count = count($result_set);

if($count>0){

    //if $count>0 show something special

    while($row = array_shift($result_set)){

        // my code

    }
    
    //if $count>0 show something special here too

}else{

    //some message

}
```

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: We don't know what `$db` is.

Comment: @slepic everyone that knows PDO knows it a connection

Comment: I know `PDO`, I could have imagined that `$db` is a `PDO` instance. But you didn't say it is, so I actually couldn't know that. Better be explicit than have us assume something...

Comment: If the only thing you need is how many rows -- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...;`  This is likely to be the fastest way to get _just_ that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *in order to know whether your query returned any rows*, in a modern web application it is preferred to fetch the data in a variable first and then use this variable to see whether it's empty or not. In this regard,   calling the `count()` function would be also superfluous. In PHP, an array is as good in the `if` statement as a boolean value.

Also, `foreach` is generally used to iterate over arrays.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$result_set = $result->fetchAll();

if($result_set){

    //if $count>0 show something special

    foreach($result_set as $row){

        // my code
    }

}else{

    //some message

}
```

A few obvious notes:

- you should never select more rows than going to be used on a single web page
- you should never select the actual rows from the database only to count them
- in case you are working with a large dataset (in a command line utility for example), it is unwise to fetch all the rows first. in this case other means of detecting whether your query returned any rows have to be used.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Count is useful and needed if i need to check if count is for example 2 `if($count==2){//do stuff}`

Comment: You should never select rows from the database to count them. in this regard, you should  NOT have used mysql_num_rows either.

Comment: Any example/advice then how i should use?

Comment: I believe Google can answer such a question like "how to count rows in the database"

Comment: Well i already know there are option to make second query. .. but is it even better?

Comment: What's the second query? Can you explain what's the use of this `if($count==2)` condition? but n case if you are asking about arrays - yes, you can have the number of array elements using count() function

Comment: lets say i need to echo different content if there are different count of email addreses for user in database

Comment: now we are getting back to my other comment. if you need the "count of email addresses", but not addresses themselves, then you shouldn't select them in the first place, but should select the count. if you need both addresses and, for some strange reason, the count, then you can always count the number of elements in the array, but that's already irrelevant to any pdo or mysqli function

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase it with some rhetorical questions. You want to replace `if($result->num_rows){}` with the following?

```
$result_set = $result->fetchAll();
$count = count($result_set);
if($count>0){}
```

That is, you are asking, should the faster and shorter code be replaced with slower and larger code?

Comment: I m not sure if i follow

Comment: In a modern web application that's rather a standard approach, however allegedly "slower" or "bigger" it is.

Comment: @Ingus In your case `$count` and `$result->num_rows` are equivalent. That is, the `$result` object already contains information about the number of rows, so it is redundant to `fetch all rows` and use the `count()` function in order to find out the answer to an already known question. Of course, if necessary, you can use it as `if($result->num_rows==2){//do stuff}` or `$count = $result->num_rows`. By the way, in your case it would have been better if you had called `$result->fetchAll()` only if `$result->num_rows > 0`.